# How do I achieve Change Data Capture in CnosDB

Tags: clickhouse, cnosdb

I am migrating some of the IoT data from MySQL to [CnosDB](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/query/database.html) and then replicate some of the anomalies and also the changes/delta of the change to ClickHouse for further analysis.

Currently I have to do full replication (similar to full backup). Is there an easy way to just replicate the change data from CnosDB to ClickHouse. FYI. I am using the Kafka in the middle to stream the data.

Comment: https://kb.altinity.com/altinity-kb-integrations/mysql-clickhouse/

Comment: It's unclear what do you mean by changes? Deltas in values? Rows Updates? Rows Deletes?

Comment: Clickhouse is able to ingest data from Kafka. See Kafka Engine. See kafka connect https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/kafka/intro/

Comment: I just updated the question. I mean the deltas.